# Why am I getting results with the same script?

Tags: python

I have the following script (see below), however I am getting two different results with from two txt files. The first txt file contains five sequences and the second txt file contains a single sequence that is present in the first file.

Sequences in the first file:

KLSEQESLL

RVRFFFPSL

QVHPQKVT

SLDDYNHLV

HLFGYSWYK

Sequences in the first file:

KLSEQESLL

Note: The sequence KLSEQESLL is common in both files as mentioned above

Code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:

    for my_kmer in f:

        KARP850103 = {'A': 0.892, 'L': 0.921, 'R': 0.901, 'K': 1.057, 'N': 0.930,
                      'M': 0.804, 'D': 0.932, 'F': 0.914, 'C': 0.925, 'P': 0.932,
                      'Q': 0.885, 'S': 0.923, 'E': 0.933, 'T': 0.934, 'G': 0.923,
                      'W': 0.803, 'H': 0.894, 'Y': 0.837, 'I': 0.872, 'V': 0.913}
        BUNA790102 = {'A': 4.349, 'L': 4.385, 'R': 4.396, 'K': 4.358, 'N': 4.755,
                      'M': 4.513, 'D': 4.765, 'F': 4.663, 'C': 4.686, 'P': 4.471,
                      'Q': 4.373, 'S': 4.498, 'E': 4.295, 'T': 4.346, 'G': 3.972,
                      'W': 4.702, 'H': 4.630, 'Y': 4.604, 'I': 4.224, 'V': 4.184}
        VINM940101 = {'A': 0.984, 'L': 0.935, 'R': 1.008, 'K': 1.102, 'N': 1.048,
                      'M': 0.952, 'D': 1.068, 'F': 0.915, 'C': 0.906, 'P': 1.049,
                      'Q': 1.037, 'S': 1.046, 'E': 1.094, 'T': 0.997, 'G': 1.031,
                      'W': 0.904, 'H': 0.950, 'Y': 0.929, 'I': 0.927, 'V': 0.931}
        KARP850102 = {'A': 0.946, 'L': 0.961, 'R': 1.028, 'K': 1.082, 'N': 1.006,
                      'M': 0.862, 'D': 1.089, 'F': 0.912, 'C': 0.878, 'P': 1.085,
                      'Q': 1.025, 'S': 1.048, 'E': 1.036, 'T': 1.051, 'G': 1.042,
                      'W': 0.917, 'H': 0.952, 'Y': 0.930, 'I': 0.892, 'V': 0.927}
        KARP850101 = {'A': 1.041, 'L': 0.967, 'R': 1.038, 'K': 1.093, 'N': 1.117,
                      'M': 0.947, 'D': 1.033, 'F': 0.930, 'C': 0.960, 'P': 1.055,
                      'Q': 1.165, 'S': 1.169, 'E': 1.094, 'T': 1.073, 'G': 1.142,
                      'W': 0.925, 'H': 0.982, 'Y': 0.961, 'I': 1.002, 'V': 0.982}
        ANDN920101 = {'A': 4.35, 'L': 4.17, 'R': 4.38, 'K': 4.36, 'N': 4.75,
                      'M': 4.52, 'D': 4.76, 'F': 4.66, 'C': 4.65, 'P': 4.44,
                      'Q': 4.37, 'S': 4.50, 'E': 4.29, 'T': 4.35, 'G': 3.97,
                      'W': 4.70, 'H': 4.63, 'Y': 4.60, 'I': 3.95, 'V': 3.95}
        FASG760104 = {'A': 9.69, 'L': 9.60, 'R': 8.99, 'K': 9.18, 'N': 8.80,
                      'M': 9.21, 'D': 9.60, 'F': 9.18, 'C': 8.35, 'P': 10.64,
                      'Q': 9.13, 'S': 9.21, 'E': 9.67, 'T': 9.10, 'G': 9.78,
                      'W': 9.44, 'H': 9.17, 'Y': 9.11, 'I': 9.68, 'V': 9.62}

        aaindex_values = []
        aaindex_listT = [VINM940103, VINM940104, VINM940102, KARP850103, BUNA790102, VINM940101, 
                        KARP850102, KARP850101, ANDN920101, FASG760104]
        for i in aaindex_listT:
            a_a = (my_kmer.count("A") * i["A"])
            c_c = (my_kmer.count("C") * i["C"])
            d_d = (my_kmer.count("D") * i["D"])
            e_e = (my_kmer.count("E") * i["E"])
            f_f = (my_kmer.count("F") * i["F"])
            g_g = (my_kmer.count("G") * i["G"])
            h_h = (my_kmer.count("H") * i["H"])
            i_i = (my_kmer.count("I") * i["I"])
            k_k = (my_kmer.count("K") * i["K"])
            l_l = (my_kmer.count("L") * i["L"])
            m_m = (my_kmer.count("M") * i["M"])
            n_n = (my_kmer.count("N") * i["N"])
            p_p = (my_kmer.count("P") * i["P"])
            q_q = (my_kmer.count("Q") * i["Q"])
            r_r = (my_kmer.count("R") * i["R"])
            s_s = (my_kmer.count("S") * i["S"])
            t_t = (my_kmer.count("T") * i["T"])
            v_v = (my_kmer.count("V") * i["V"])
            w_w = (my_kmer.count("W") * i["W"])
            y_y = (my_kmer.count("Y") * i["Y"])

            aaindex_comp = round(((a_a + c_c + d_d + e_e + f_f + g_g + h_h + i_i + k_k + l_l + m_m + n_n 
                                   + p_p + q_q + r_r + s_s + t_t + v_v + w_w + y_y)/len(my_kmer)), 3)

            aaindex_values.append(aaindex_comp)

        print(aaindex_values)
```

Result for the KLSEQESLL sequence are different in both cases

Doubt:
Why are the results different?

Comment: Can you post some results?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the future. This is a lot of code, 90% of it irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not taking into account the newline characters (`\n` and possibly `\r`) which occur at the end of lines.  If you iterate over the lines of a file, you'll get those characters.  For example, suppose I have the following file (file.txt):

```
foo
bar
blah
```

If I run

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines=[line for line in f]
```

the elements of `lines` will be `'foo\n'`, `'bar\n'`, and `'blah'`.  Notice that the last one won't have a newline character because it is the last line.

When you read in KLSEQESLL from the first file, it isn't the last line and so it'll have a `'\n'` at the end.  That matters when you compute `len(my_kmer)`.

In the second file, the KLSEQESLL is the last line and thus there isn't a newline character at the end making `len(my_kmer)` different.

What you should do is this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for my_kmer in f:
        my_kmer = my_kmer.rstrip()
        ...
```

That will strip off, among other things, any newline characters.

Comment: BTW, Unix technically requires that lines end with newlines. In practice though, it depends on your text editor. Anyway, just mentioning here in case anyone isn't able to reproduce the problem from the question.